# Is the any way to run Typescript by terminal right after coding?

Tags: typescript

With `Nodejs`, I can easily use `Javascript` shell by type `node` in the terminal.

How can I do to use a shell like this to run `Typescript`? I want to write and run the code right after inserting the code, is this possible with Typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ts-node` equivalent: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node

Comment: Ah thank you. I installed globally typescript but I forgot `ts-node`. My bad.